# Removing iframe tags in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress theme and WP now uses oEmbed to automatically turn known links into widgets. The problem here is that the widgets are not responsive (they do not keep the same aspect ratio and adjust to the screen size).

The site is http://testsite1.seyoum.net/
Note that the theme I am using is a child theme of twentyfifteen. You can download the theme files here:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B9CDD4D34FF06A75!97938&authkey=!AEj9VpYkCRL0SEE&ithint=file%2crar

I have done some research and found this video: https://youtu.be/Dm0YnuQeROI
In the video he removes the with and height properties of the iframe. The problem for me is that these tags are added automatically by oEmbedd so I need some kind of filter that removes/ignores the height and width tags in the iframe.

I am trying to alter an iframe. More spesifically I want to remove the height and width tags of the iframe by using (what I believe to be) filters.

Example:
I want to change this

```
<iframe width="660" height="400" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?visual=true&amp;color=000000&amp;download=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;sharing=false&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_playcount=false&amp;hide_related=true&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F192992432&amp;show_artwork=false&amp;&amp;"></iframe>
```

To this:
(The width="660" height="400" is gone)

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?visual=true&amp;color=000000&amp;download=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;sharing=false&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_playcount=false&amp;hide_related=true&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F192992432&amp;show_artwork=false&amp;&amp;"></iframe>
```

I am not familiar with php and it is hard to find articles I can understand so please help me out if you can.

Comment: with should be define or use auto

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
function mycustom_embed_defaults($embed_size){ 
    // Applies for all embedded media 
    /*$embed_size['width'] = 827;*/ // Adjust the width of the player 
    // $embed_size['height'] = 120; // Adjust the height of the player 
    unset($embed_size['width']); 
    unset($embed_size['height']); 
    return $embed_size; // Return new size 
}
```

or

```
function mycustom_embed_defaults($embed_size){ 
    // Applies for all embedded media 
    $embed_size['width'] = "auto"; // Adjust the width of the player 
    $embed_size['height'] = "auto"; // Adjust the height of the player 
    return $embed_size; // Return new size 
}
```

or

```
function mycustom_embed_defaults($embed_size){ 
    // Applies for all embedded media 
    $embed_size['width'] = "100%"; // Adjust the width of the player 
    $embed_size['height'] = "100%"; // Adjust the height of the player 
    return $embed_size; // Return new size 
}
```

The problem is that your plugin seems to need the width property... All you have to do is to know what you want it to be... It doesn't have to be a pixel value...

Comment: The last suggestion `$embed_size['width'] = "100%";` produces `<iframe width="100" height="` But the problem is that I actually need to remove the height and width properties, not change them. Also I do not use a plugin. The embedding is Wordpress' default oEmbed

Comment: Sorry but I am completely lost. I probably lack basic knowledge of PHP. I am tempted to just re-write the question and ask **"how can I remove height and width properties from an iframe without actually deleting these values from the iframe itself"** Perhaps it is better to start from scratch.

Comment: I think it's better to start a new question and try to go over this from scratch. I did look for the "embed_defaults" in every php file but I could not find it. This means that I must have screwed up something from the beginning. I think I will need some help from scratch to even set up the php right, sorry. Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you can't find it, it is because it is never called, indeed, did you make this function yourself (using copy paste for a FAQ) ? You may have missed a part then

Comment: I probably did miss that part, yes. So how do I call it? My php skills are horrible.

Comment: It depends where you want it to be called. I don't know iframe at all... where did you see you could do what you tried ?